# User defined array sizes in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm reading through "Illustrated C" and the first exercise question asks:

> Program MATMUL multiplies matrices of fixed size. Make the program deal with any specified sizes.

So below is the code that I have come up with thus far. However I read that all attributes need to be declared before the main function. So how do I get custom sized arrays without declaring them in the main function?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>

int n, m, i, j, k;

int main(void)
{
    printf("\nEnter:rows for A, columns for A and rows for B, columns for B\n");
    scanf("%i %i %i", &i, &j, &k);
    float A[i][j], B[j][k], C[i][k];    //Not legal, right?

    /*Read in A array*/
    for(n=0; n<i; ++n)
        for(m=0; m<j; ++m)
            scanf("%f", &A[n][m]);

    /*Read in B array*/
    for(n=0; n<j; ++n)
        for(m=0; m<k; ++m)
            scanf("%f", &B[n][m]);

    /*Calculate C array*/
    for(j=0; j<i; ++j)
        for(i=0; i<k; ++i)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (k=0; k<j; ++k)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
    for(n=0; n<i; ++n)
         for(m=0; m<k; ++m)
        printf("\n%.2f\t", C[n][m]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should at least compile your code to see what happens before posting here. ?  Then you would find out that you did the right thing.  (You have other errors in your code, which is how I know you didn't compile it.)

Comment: @cape1232: I did compile the code, but since most of the errors related to `'A' : undeclared identifier` I thought I would fix the array problem. The loops and semi-colons I can deal with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> float A[i][j], B[j][k], C[i][k];    //Not legal, right?

Your question has been tagged `C` and [VLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are part of C99, so `float A[i][j], B[j][k], C[i][k];` is legal.

**EDIT**

If your compiler doesn't support C99 then you are left with no option other than `dynamic memory allocation`.

Example:

```
  float **A;
  int l;
  A= (float**)malloc(i*sizeof(float*));
  for(l=0;l<i;++l)
     A[l]= (float*)malloc(j*sizeof(float));
```

---

**Note**: *Do not forget to `free` the memory when you are done*.

Comment: His problem might be, that a variable declaration is not allowed at this point. Add some `{}` or use a second method ...

Comment: IF your compiler conforms to C99. If you need to support a compiler that doesn't (they are still out there) then you should know how to do it both ways (with malloc and without)

Comment: `If you need to support a compiler that doesn't (they are still out there) ` then I'd tell them to upgrade their compilers.

Comment: @A Levy: Compiling with Visual C++ Express 2008, is it C99 compliant?

Comment: No, MSVC does not support C99.

Comment: If you take Prasoon's advice and upgrade your compiler then use VLAs, make sure you don't allow insanely large dimensions. GCC puts VLAs on the stack.

Comment: I installed CodeBlocks so I can compile with GNU GCC.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to allocate the memory to store the array dynamically. Somewhere along the line of:

```
float *a;
int siz;    /* store user input here */

/* <snip> */

/* allocate a float array with `siz` elements */
a = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * siz);
```

NOTE: Adjust accordingly for two-dimensional arrays.

Comment: I wouldn't say he needs to, more like "he can also".

Comment: Why was this answer down-voted? Perhaps he should have done an explicit cast to (float *) of the malloced memory, but this answer is correct.