# i need to take size of the matrix from user

Tags: c, matrix, rows

i want to create a matrix in C, but size of the matrix must be determine by user.There is my code.

```
int row1,column1;
printf("Please enter number of rows in first matrix: ");
scanf("%d",&row1);
printf("Please enter number of columns in first matrix: ");
scanf("%d",&column1);
int M1[row1][column1];
```

i get errors with row1 and column1(in the last line).What is the correct way of taking size of a matrix from an user?

Comment: [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

You have to dynamically allocate the array as you don't know the size at compile time.

My hint: use a single array it's much simpler:

```
int M1[] = new int[row1 * column1];
```

Then address it as

```
M1[column + line * row1];
```

If you absolutely need a 2D matrix, refer to this question: [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

And don't forget to delete[] properly your array.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you cannot initialize an array with array length as a variable. Declare a pointer and use [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) to dynamically allocate the array.

```
int row1,column1;
printf("Please enter number of rows in first matrix: ");
scanf("%d",&row1);
printf("Please enter number of columns in first matrix: ");
scanf("%d",&column1);

int **arr;

//allocate the memory
arr=malloc(sizeof(int*)*row1);

int i;
for (i=0;i<row1;i++)
  *(arr+i)=malloc(sizeof(int)*column1);


//do what you want to do


//free the memory
for (i=0;i<row1;i++)
  free(*(arr+i));

free(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Related: [dynamic allocating array of arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455960/dynamic-allocating-array-of-arrays-in-c)

First allocate an array of pointers:

```
M1 = (int**)malloc(row1 * sizeof(int*));
```

And then point each to another array.

```
for(i = 0; i < row1; i++)
  M1[i] = (int*)malloc(column1 * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

In c to create matrix of user defined size you need to use dynamic allocation using malloc or alloca(). you can read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283013/user-defined-array-sizes-in-c) to get information on creating arrays of user defined size in c